# <p> tag alignment issue

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <style type="text/css">
        .test span:first-child{font-weight: 900;color: #333;margin-right: 15px;display: inline-block;width: 40px;}
        .test{position: relative;}
        @media (min-width: 1200px){
        .test p:nth-last-child(1) {float: right;display: inline-block;position: absolute;top: 37px;right: 0%;margin-top: 0;}
        .test p:nth-last-child(2) {float: right;position: absolute;top: 0px;right: 0%;display: inline-block;margin-top: 0;}
        }
        @media (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
        .test p:nth-last-child(1) {float: right;display: inline-block;position: absolute;top: 37px;right: -50%;margin-top: 0;}
        .test p:nth-last-child(2) {float: right;position: absolute;top: 0px;right: -50%;display: inline-block;margin-top: 0;}
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-24 test">       
                <p><span>Mon</span><span>9 am - 10 pm</span></p>        
                <p><span>Tue</span><span>9 am - 10 pm</span></p>        
                <p><span>Wed</span><span>9 am - 10 pm</span></p>        
                <p><span>Thur</span><span>9 am - 10 pm</span></p>       
                <p><span>Fri</span><span>8 am - 11 pm</span></p>        
                <p><span>Sat</span><span>8 am - 11 pm</span></p>        
                <p><span>Sun</span><span>Closed - </span></p>       
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Right side `<p>` tag is not getting aligned,when content changes in `<p>` tag.
How to make right side `<p>` tags align even when content changes ?
On first `<p>` tag you see day & time
but in second `<p>` tag you see closed

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/068etmg3/)

Answer (score 1):

because you are using bootstrap have a look on the offset columns

a problem can be that bootstrap uses float in the col-* classes too

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <p class="row">
      <span class="col-sm-3">Column 1</span>
      <span class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-6">Column 3</span>
      <!-- the offset css class adds empty cols before the element -->
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

perhaps this is a solution for you

Answer (score 0):

Use table instead for your structure

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <style type="text/css">
        .test span:first-child{font-weight: 900;color: #333;margin-right: 15px;display: inline-block;width: 40px;}
        .test{position: relative;}
        @media (min-width: 1200px){
        .test p:nth-last-child(1) {float: right;display: inline-block;position: absolute;top: 37px;right: 0%;margin-top: 0;}
        .test p:nth-last-child(2) {float: right;position: absolute;top: 0px;right: 0%;display: inline-block;margin-top: 0;}
        }
        @media (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
        .test p:nth-last-child(1) {float: right;display: inline-block;position: absolute;top: 37px;right: -50%;margin-top: 0;}
        .test p:nth-last-child(2) {float: right;position: absolute;top: 0px;right: -50%;display: inline-block;margin-top: 0;}
        }
        table td{
            padding-right: 50px;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 test">       
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span>Mon</span><span>9 am - 10 pm</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Sat</span><span>8 am - 11 pm</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span>Tue</span><span>9 am - 10 pm</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Sun</span><span>Closed - </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span>Wed</span><span>9 am - 10 pm</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span>Thur</span><span>9 am - 10 pm</span>  
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span>Fri</span><span>8 am - 11 pm</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why there is class `col-xs-24` ?

Comment: I have modified just the inner container structure leaving the rest as such

Comment: Hi @Karthikeyansundaramoorthi,  all the data will be dynamically generated , so i don't have control on it. so only i using css to move last two childs to right side.